# Working with multiple graphs in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Can someone explain to me how `name_scope` works in TensorFlow?

Suppose I have the following code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

g1 = tf.Graph()
with g1.as_default() as g:
    with g.name_scope( "g1" ) as scope:
        matrix1 = tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
        matrix2 = tf.constant([[2.],[2.]])
        product = tf.matmul(matrix1, matrix2)

tf.reset_default_graph()

g2 = tf.Graph()
with g2.as_default() as g:
    with g.name_scope( "g2" ) as scope:
        matrix1 = tf.constant([[4., 4.]])
        matrix2 = tf.constant([[5.],[5.]])
        product = tf.matmul(matrix1, matrix2)

tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.Session( graph = g1 ) as sess:
    result = sess.run( product )
    print( result )
```

When I run this code I get the following error message:

```
Tensor Tensor("g2/MatMul:0", shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I agree "g2/MatMul" is not an element of graph `g1`, but why is it selecting "g2/MatMul" when the session graph is set to `g1`? Why doesn't it select "g1/MatMul"?

---

#### Edit

The following code seems to work:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

g1 = tf.Graph()
with g1.as_default() as g:
    with g.name_scope( "g1" ) as g1_scope:
        matrix1 = tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
        matrix2 = tf.constant([[2.],[2.]])
        product = tf.matmul( matrix1, matrix2, name = "product")

tf.reset_default_graph()

g2 = tf.Graph()
with g2.as_default() as g:
    with g.name_scope( "g2" ) as g2_scope:
        matrix1 = tf.constant([[4., 4.]])
        matrix2 = tf.constant([[5.],[5.]])
        product = tf.matmul( matrix1, matrix2, name = "product" )

tf.reset_default_graph()

use_g1 = False

if ( use_g1 ):
    g = g1
    scope = g1_scope
else:
    g = g2
    scope = g2_scope

with tf.Session( graph = g ) as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables()
    result = sess.run( sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name( scope + "product:0" ) )
    print( result )
```

By flipping the switch `use_g1`, graph `g1` or `g2` will run in the session. Is this the way name scoping was meant to work?

Comment: How bad is the overhead of switching graphs and sessions? Is it feasible to use this approach to constantly swaps between 2 graphs if I want them to play a sequential game against each other?

Comment: This is rather a Python problem than Tensorflow. Your "g1" graph still exists but you lost reference to it since you point it to "g2". Replace graphs with two lists may make it more clear.

Answer (score 17):

Your `product` is a global variable, and you've set it to point to "g2/MatMul".

In particular

Try

```
print product
```

and you'll see

```
Tensor("g2/MatMul:0", shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
```

So the system takes `"g2/MatMul:0"` since that's the Tensor's name, and tries to find it in the graph `g1` since that's the graph you set for the session. Incidentally you can see all nodes in the graph `print [n.name for n in g1.as_graph_def().node]`

Generally, using more than one graph is rarely useful. You can't merge them and can't pass tensors between them. I'd recommend just doing

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.Constant(2)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
....
```

This way you'll have one default graph and one default session and you can omit specifying graph or session in most cases. If you ever need to refer to them explicitly, you can get them from `tf.get_default_graph()` or `tf.get_default_session()`

Comment: I agree, you can always stick with the default graph, but since the developers explicitly built an API with multiple graphs in mind, the question is how to use it. From what you are saying, all variables in each graph need unique global names. If that were the case, it is not clear why they introduced the concept of "name scope" or how it should be used.

Comment: `name_scope("g2")` prepends `g2/` to all the Tensor names that are created inside that scope, so your "scope-switching" has no effect since the tensors have already been created

Comment: Is there no documentation for how to use multiple graphs in TensorFlow?

Comment: Using more than one graph in a process is generally a terrible mistake

Comment: so if I want to run random search to select different hyper parameters between different runs, how is one suppose to do it without having more than one tensorflow graph?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, will it solve the problem if using variable_scope("g2") and get_variable()?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Actually, using more than one graph in a process can be a recommended practice for advanced use cases (see: https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py, and notice the use of two sessions and graphs). Training Graphs contain Operations such as optimizers and loss criterion functions that can be omitted from evaluation graphs. This simplifies the model during export for Serving, and requires less Constant Operation conversions. Also, some TF-Estimator's use two graphs: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs#building_a_tfgraph

Answer (score 7):

This is quite the necro, but it's still a top search result for questions related to this and I thought it might help to make very explicit something that the prior answers (which are correct) note in passing:

The Q's variable `product` is a *python* variable. As such, it points to an object: When defined, it points to the `tf.Tensor` output of the matmul `tf.Operation` defined in the name_scope 'g1'. It is later redefined to point to a different object, the `tf.Tensor` output of 'g2'. This python variable has never heard of `tf.name_scope`s and doesn't care.

*That* is why you need to do lookups by the name attributes of the tensorflow objects... Those, by use of name_scopes, are unique and accessible. Or generate distinct python variables--that are unique and accessible according to python scoping rules--to point to each `tf.Tensor` object you want to reference.

Dunno if this is helpful for anybody else, but if I ever forget, I'll thank my past self for this.

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar difficulties dealing with multiple graphs on a IPython notebook. What works for my purposes is to encapsulate each graph and its session in a function. I realize this is more of a hack I guess, I don't know anything about namespaces and I know OP wanted something along those lines. Maybe it will help someone I dunno, you can also pass results between computations.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def Graph1():
    g1 = tf.Graph()
    with g1.as_default() as g:
        matrix1 = tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
        matrix2 = tf.constant([[2.],[2.]])
        product = tf.matmul( matrix1, matrix2, name = "product")

    with tf.Session( graph = g ) as sess:
        tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
        return product


def Graph2(incoming):
    i = incoming
    g2 = tf.Graph()
    with g2.as_default() as g:
        matrix1 = tf.constant([[4., 4.]])
        matrix2 = tf.constant([[5.],[5.]])
        product = tf.matmul( matrix1, matrix2, name = "product" )

    with tf.Session( graph = g ) as sess:
        tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
        print product
        print i

print Graph1()

Graph2(Graph1())
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are calling the latest variable `product` which points to a tensor created on g2 - you overwrote it in your second scope. Just relabel all your variables and you should be good to go. The working code is below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

g1 = tf.Graph() with g1.as_default() as g:
    with g.name_scope( "g1" ) as scope:
        matrix11 = tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
        matrix21 = tf.constant([[2.],[2.]])
        product1 = tf.matmul(matrix11, matrix21)

tf.reset_default_graph()

g2 = tf.Graph() with g2.as_default() as g:
    with g.name_scope( "g2" ) as scope:
        matrix12 = tf.constant([[4., 4.]])
        matrix22 = tf.constant([[5.],[5.]])
        product2 = tf.matmul(matrix12, matrix22)

tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.Session( graph = g1 ) as sess:
    result = sess.run( product1 )
    print( result )
```

Comment: But intuitively it seems that even though the variables have the same name, they belong to different name_scopes and thus should not be confused?

Comment: But `g.name_scope` is a scope for the GPU only not the python code. `With tf.Graph` does not create a pythonic local scope like inside a function or a method - instead it indicates to the GPU how the variables should be labelled. While the local variable `product` is a pointer to the graph computations on the gpu. If these sections of code were different functions then you could keep the same names.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 graphs , not 2 graphs ( g1 or g2 ) .

You can see 3 graphs by id()

```
...

print 'g1           ', id(g1)
print 'g2           ', id(g2)
print 'current graph', id ( tf.get_default_graph() )

with tf.Session( graph = g1 ) as sess:
    result = sess.run( product )
    print( result )
```

Using "with g1.as_default(): " make the same error

```
...

with g1.as_default() :
    with tf.Session( graph = g1 ) as sess:
        result = sess.run( product )
        print( result )
```

Because, you have two 'product' , not one.

```
g1 = tf.Graph()
with g1.as_default() as g:
    ...
    print 'g1 product', id ( product )

...

g2 = tf.Graph()
with g2.as_default() as g:
    ...
    print 'g2 product', id ( product )

with tf.Session( graph = g1 ) as sess:
    print 'last product', id(product)
    ...
```

last product == g2 product

```
...
    product = tf.matmul(matrix1, matrix2, name='g1_product')
...
with g1.as_default() as g:
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        product = g.get_tensor_by_name(  "g1_product:0" )
        result = sess.run( product )
        print( result )
```

Above code work.

But, two variables with the same name ( product )

Encapsulating with class is good?

Answer (score 0):

I have written two snippets to do what you are trying to do.

The first switches between graphs and does NOT use name_scope. The second uses the default_graph for both ops and uses name_scope to switch between them...

```
import tensorflow as tf

g1 = tf.Graph()
with g1.as_default() as g:
  matrix1 = tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
  matrix2 = tf.constant([[2.],[2.]])
  tf.matmul(matrix1, matrix2, name="productX")

g2 = tf.Graph()
with g2.as_default() as g:
  matrix1 = tf.constant([[4., 4.]])
  matrix2 = tf.constant([[5.],[5.]])
  tf.matmul(matrix1, matrix2, name="productX")

product_op = g1.get_tensor_by_name(  "productX:0" )
with tf.Session( graph = g1 ) as sess:
    result = sess.run( product_op )
    print( result )

product_op = g2.get_tensor_by_name(  "productX:0" )
with tf.Session( graph = g2 ) as sess:
  result = sess.run( product_op )
  print( result )
```

NOTE A) I have taken out the resetting of the default graph (the default graph is never used) and B) I have gotten rid of the 'product' variable and given the operation a name, instead

The important switching code is...

```
product_op = g2.get_tensor_by_name(  "productX:0" )
```

where we are using the variable name of the two graphs to distinguish between the two product ops.

NOTE the annoying ':0' that you have to put at the end of the variable name.

And now using name_scope...

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.get_default_graph()

matrix1 = tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
matrix2 = tf.constant([[2.],[2.]])
with g.name_scope("prodA"):
  tf.matmul(matrix1, matrix2, name="productX")

matrix1 = tf.constant([[4., 4.]])
matrix2 = tf.constant([[5.],[5.]])
with g.name_scope("prodB"):
  tf.matmul(matrix1, matrix2, name="productX")

with tf.Session() as sess:

  product_op = g.get_tensor_by_name(  "prodA/productX:0" )
  result = sess.run( product_op )
  print( result )

  product_op = g.get_tensor_by_name(  "prodB/productX:0" )
  result = sess.run( product_op )
  print( result )
```

Now the switching line of code is this...

```
product_op = g.get_tensor_by_name(  "prodB/productX:0" )
```

NOTE A) There is no switching between graphs or sessions. B) name_scope give you a kind of directory structure looking name hierarchy.

What are the pros and cons of graph vs name_scope switching? If someone wrote a blog on that, I would read it!

I don't imagine that switching between graphs and sessions can be very fast, however.

Comment: Don't leave some questions in your answer. Please edit it.