# How can I build a TF Graph for both training and inference with tf.train.shuffle_batch?

Tags: tensorflow

Context: Convolutional Autoencoder

I add the input_tensor and output_tensor to the graph with tf.add_to_collections()

```
Input to neural network from shuffle batch: [batch_size, patch_size, patch_size, depth]
During training, this is [512, 32, 32, 3]

Input to neural network for inference: [batch_size, height, width, depth]
During inference, this can be [1, 100, 100, 3], or [3, 150, 150, 3], etc.
```

During inference, I call tf.get_collections() to extract these nodes and then call a sess.run(). It says that the shape is fixed at [512, 32, 32, 3], how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution is to use a [`tf.placeholder_with_default()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder_with_default) op to relax the shape requirement on the input op. For example:

```
input_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(..., batch_size=512)

input_placeholder = tf.placeholder_with_default(input_batch, [None, None, None, 3])
```

If you run code that depends on `input_placeholder` but don't feed it, it will use the result of `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`. Alternatively, if you feed a value for `input_placeholder` you can feed any 4-D tensor (with depth 3), so you can use any batch size or image size.

Note, however, that doing this will disable some optimizations in training, because the shape of each batch can now vary, at least in principle. This prevents TensorFlow from considering some internal [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shape) calls as constant values, which might mean that it needs to do more work on each training step. In the end, it may be better to build two separate graphs for training and inference, as these can be optimized separately.

Comment: Referencing [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955144/working-with-multiple-graphs-in-tensorflow). Yaroslav mentioned that it is rarely useful to have more than one graph. How should we do this? I have asked another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352841/how-can-i-build-a-tf-graph-that-has-separate-inference-and-training-parts).