# How can I build a TF Graph that has separate inference and training parts?

Tags: tensorflow

Referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340807/how-can-i-build-a-tf-graph-for-both-training-and-inference-with-tf-train-shuffle) asked previously, as the suggestion was to create a graph that has separate inference and training parts.

Boilerplate code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MNIST convolution in the repository is an example -- [tensorflow/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8e48ec6ea0492e2cb9fd19c0a2ccf41afc7b4dc6/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py)

It follows a pattern when you factor out model construction code into a function (`model` in `convolutional.py`), and call it separately for the eval and training parts

```
 logits = model(train_data_node, True)
 loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
      logits, train_labels_node))
 eval_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(eval_data))
```

For training you feed into `train_data_node` and minimize `loss`, for eval, you feed into `eval_data` node and get the results at `eval_prediction`

Comment: What's the motivation for using separate models and sessions for training and inference? I'm having a hard time understanding it.