# Tensorflow data saving with two separate models

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I have used tf to make two separate models. During training I saved each one alone. Now I want to use them both. I can use the first one but when I try to load the second one I get this message (in part):

```
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 850M, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0)
    W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:968] Invalid argument: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [5,5,32,64] rhs shape= [1024,2]
         [[Node: save_1/Assign_16 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_6"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Variable_6, save_1/restore_slice_16/_47)]]
```

also there was a message signifying that the error took place in the 'restore' part of the code. Here's a snippet of that code:

```
def save(self):
    filename = self.save_name
    folder = self.ckpt_folder + os.sep + "ckpt"
    if not os.path.exists(folder) :
        os.makedirs(folder)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    save_path = saver.save(self.sess, folder + os.sep + self.ckpt_name + "."+ filename)
    print ("saved?", filename)

def load(self):
    filename = self.save_name
    file = self.ckpt_folder + os.sep + "ckpt" + os.sep + self.ckpt_name +"."+ filename
    if os.path.isfile(file) :
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(self.sess, file)
        print ("load?", filename)
```

The functions above, and specifically the load() is called by the model after the session object is initialized. How can I run both tf models together from the data I have already saved??

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with them, you should either:

- [Use name scoping to make them unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747769/using-two-different-models-in-tensorflow)
- [Load them into separate graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955144/working-with-multiple-graphs-in-tensorflow)

Comment: I think I loaded them in separate graphs, tearing down the first one when the second was about to be loaded.