# Using two different models in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im trying to use two different mobilenet  models. Following is the code as of how I initialize the model.

```
def initialSetup():
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()

    # This takes 2-5 seconds to run
    # Unpersists graph from file
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile('age/output_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
        age_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        age_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(age_graph_def, name='')

    with tf.gfile.FastGFile('output_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
        gender_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        gender_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(gender_graph_def, name='')

    print ('Took {} seconds to unpersist the graph'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time))
```

since both are two different models, how do I use it for predictions?

**UPDATE**

```
initialSetup()

age_session = tf.Session(graph=age_graph_def)
gender_session = tf.Session(graph=gender_graph_def)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()

    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = age_session.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    print ('Took {} seconds to feed data to graph'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time))

    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
```

**ERROR**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Desktop/untitled/testimg/testimg/combo.py", line 48, in
>   
>       age_session = tf.Session(graph=age_graph_def)   File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1292, in **init**
>       super(Session, self).**init**(target, graph, config=config)   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 529, in **init**
>       raise TypeError('graph must be a tf.Graph, but got %s' % type(graph)) TypeError: graph must be a tf.Graph, but got  Exception ignored in:
>   > Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 587, in **del**
>       if self._session is not None: AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute '_session'

Comment: Have you successfully used a single model loaded this way? The usual approach would be to pass different non-empty `name` arguments to each of the `tf.import_graph_def()` calls, and then use those names as the prefix to the particular tensors in each model that you want to feed and fetch.

Comment: yes individually it is working.if I add name, it says, no such tensor exists

Comment: Can you add the code that you're using to invoke the session, and the full error that is printed? If you add a `name` to the imported graph, you'll need to prefix any tensor names that you use in that graph with the value of `name` followed by a `/`.

Comment: please check the updated question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are working with multiple models in the same graph, use name scoping to give the individual tensors predictable names. For example, you could rewrite `initial_setup()` as follows:

```
def initialSetup():
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()

    # This takes 2-5 seconds to run
    # Unpersists graph from file
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile('age/output_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
        age_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        age_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(age_graph_def, name='age_model')

    with tf.gfile.FastGFile('output_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
        gender_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        gender_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(gender_graph_def, name='gender_model')

    print ('Took {} seconds to unpersist the graph'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time))
```

Now the names of all of the nodes from `age_graph_def` will be prefixed with `"age_model/"` and the names of all of the nodes from `gender_graph_def` will be prefixed with `"gender_model/"`. They are all part of the same default graph, so you can use a single `tf.Session` with no `graph` argument to access either model.

```
initialSetup()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()

    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('age_model/final_result:0')

    # Alternatively, to get a tensor from the gender model:
    # tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('gender_model/...')

    print ('Took {} seconds to feed data to graph'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time))

    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
```

Comment: thanks it works..however the frame is lagging now a bit... is there any ways to increase its speed?

Comment: will it affect the accuracy if I combine both of the classes from two models and retrain?

Comment: @mrry Works for me too, but speed a major issue! Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`tf.Session` requires a `tf.Graph` instance not `tf.GraphDef`, following step fix the issue.

```
def initialSetup():
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile('age/output_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
        age_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        age_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
            tf.import_graph_def(age_graph_def, name='')
            age_graph = graph

   ...
   return age_graph, gender_graph

age_graph, gender_graph = initial_setup() 
age_session = tf.Session(graph=age_graph)
...
# also delete the following line, as it creates another new context 
with tf.Session() as sess:
```

Comment: now it says, `KeyError: "The name 'final_result:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'final_result', does not exist in the graph."
`

Comment: it prints nothing:(

Comment: the problem is with this line `with tf.Session() as sess:` you are not supposed to define anoher session here. since `age_session` is already defined.

Comment: i tried using age_session as sess: and it says `KeyError: "The name 'final_result:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'final_result', does not exist in the graph."
`

Comment: tf.global_variables() is printing empty list

Comment: you were supoosed to print that using `age_session` context; you can find out about nodes from `age_session.graph.collections`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152238/discussion-between-hara-hara-mahadevaki-and-ishant-mrinal).