# Can we construct a graph from multiple graphs in TensorFlow?

Tags: graph, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I want to run and evaluate a very simple logistic model for binary classification.
To achieve that, I want a graph like:

1. predict label from input (may be fed with feed_dict)
2. calculate the loss and minimize it
3. compare ground truth and predicted label to calculate accuracy

When I wrote these in a single graph, it worked well.
However, the code would be much clearer if we could separate the graph.

Now, I create three separated graphs (corresponds to each of the list above).
Then, I want to construct three following graphs

- forward_graph (= graph 1)
- train_graph (= graph 1 + graph 2)
- eval_graph (= graph 1 + graph 3)

each of which can be run separately.

Is there any way to achieve this or even something like this?
I did research a lot to find the solution, however, I couldn't find the answer that helps me.

Hope someone can answer this!

Answer (score 0):

I feel first option(model, loss and accuracy in one graph) is better because all of them belongs to  one model.

Anyways, you could build three graphs and run different sessions for different graph combinations.

You might have to build graphs like this : [Working with multiple graphs in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955144/working-with-multiple-graphs-in-tensorflow)