# tensorflow summary - writing multiple graphs

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a following code using tensorflow:

```
 g1 = tf.Graph()
 g2 = tf.Graph()

 with g1.as_default():
     a = tf.constant(3)
     b = tf.constant(4)
     c = tf.add(a, b)

 with g2.as_default():
     x = tf.constant(5)
     y = tf.constant(2)
     z = tf.multiply(x, y)

 writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./graphs", g1)
 writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./graphs", g2)
 writer.close()
```

And on tensorboard, I get this:

[image]

But it is missing the first graph. Is there a way to draw both graphs?

Answer (score 3):

Your second call to `tf.summary.FileWriter` overwrites your first file.

What happens if you write to a different file, by closing the first writer before opening a second?

> WARNING:tensorflow:Found more than one graph event per run, or there was a metagraph containing a graph_def, as well as one or more graph events.  Overwriting the graph with the newest event.

So it seems tensorboard is not ready to handle more than one graph. Should we worry? To cite [Yaroslav Bulatov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955144/working-with-multiple-graphs-in-tensorflow#comment66969889_35962721),

> Using more than one graph in a process is generally a terrible mistake.

**EDIT**

Note that a tensorflow `Graph` can host several, non-connected components, effectively representing several distinct graphs. For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
     a = tf.constant(3)
     b = tf.constant(4)
     c = tf.add(a, b)

     x = tf.constant(5)
     y = tf.constant(2)
     z = tf.multiply(x, y)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./graphs", g)
writer.close()
```

results in the following

[image]

This is one of the reasons why using several `Graph`s is usually not needed.