# convolutional neural network- how to use two cnn model on same image

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I want to use two differently trained CNN (convolutional neural network) modules on the same image. I trained the two modules, 1 for detection and one for classification. Now, I want to use these two modules on the same image. The code is in python using the keras and tensorflow libraries.
[Two different CNN on the same image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFfYR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In tensorflow you need to explicitly specify [the computational graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs) for both of your models.

```
# build two separate graphs `g1` and `g2`

tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session(graph=g1) as session:
    result = sess.run(detect, feed_dict={x: test_x})
    print(result)

tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session(graph=g2) as session:
    result = sess.run(recognize, feed_dict={x: test_x})
    print(result)
```

There are also some caveats when multiple graphs are built in one application, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955144/working-with-multiple-graphs-in-tensorflow).