# Running different models in one script in Tensorflow 1.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have very simple model which consists of one `tf.Variable()` and here is who code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

save_path="model1/model1.ckpt"

num_input = 2
n_nodes_hl1 = 2

with tf.variable_scope("model1"):
        hidden_1_layer = {
                'weights' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input, n_nodes_hl1]), name='Weight1')
        }

def train_model():
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        save_model(sess)

def save_model(sess):
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), save_path)
    saver.save(sess, save_path)

def load_model(sess):
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), save_path)
    saver.restore(sess, save_path)

def run_model():
    print("model1 running...")
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        load_model(sess)
        x = sess.run(hidden_1_layer)
        print(x)

#train_model()
```

The second model is completely the same, but with changed names "model1" to "model2". Both models are trained, saved and **work perfect separately**. So now I want to test them using following script:

```
import model1 as m1
import model2 as m2

m1.run_model()
m2.run_model()
```

And here I got an error message:

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key model2/Weight2 not found in checkpoint
```

So it looks like running imports causes adding all variables to common graph (even though they are in separate variable scopes) and then it cannot find variable from model2 saved in checkpoint in model1. 
Can anyone solve my problem? 
Is it possible in Tensorflow to run a few different models in one script?

**EDIT - PROBLEM SOLVED**
The solution is very easy. What you have to do is to create separate graphs for each model like. It means that all tensors you declare or calculate must be within that graph. You also must put it as an argument in Session, like: `tf.Session(graph=self.graph)`
Whole example below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

save_path="model1/model1.ckpt"
class model1:
    num_input = 2
    n_nodes_hl1 = 2

    def init(self):
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        with self.graph.as_default():
            with tf.variable_scope("model1"):
                    self.hidden_1_layer = {
                            'weights' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.num_input, self.n_nodes_hl1]), name='Weight1')
                    }

    def train_model(self):
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        with tf.Session(graph = self.graph) as sess:
            sess.run(init)
            self.save_model(sess)

    def save_model(self, sess):
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), save_path)
        saver.save(sess, save_path)

    def load_model(self, sess):
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), save_path)
        saver.restore(sess, save_path)

    def run_model(self):
        print("model1 running...")
        with tf.Session(graph = self.graph) as sess:
            self.load_model(sess)
            x = sess.run(self.hidden_1_layer)
            print(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh! the common "I want to use several models" question! just make sure that you reset the graph after each model:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Your code would look like:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import model1 as m1
m1.run_model()

tf.reset_default_graph()

import model2 as m2
m2.run_model()
```

**Why?** The moment you create a variable in tensorflow using `tf.Variable`, that variable is added to the *default graph*. If you import both models one after the other, you just created all the variables in the *default graph*! This is by far the easiest solution. Consider the *default graph* as a blackboard: you can draw your fancy ML model, but you need to wipe it clean before reuse!

NOTE: If you are wondering, the alternative is to create **separate graphs** for each of the models, but it is much more worrysome and I only recommend it for times when you must have **both models at the same time**.

## EXTRA: Encapsulating your model in a Tensorflow class

A fancier way to do it while avoiding several graphs (seriously, it is horrible!) is to encapsulate the whole model in a class. Thus, your code would look like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class model():
    self.num_input = 2
    self.n_nodes_hl1 = 2
    def init(self, new_save_path)
        self.save_path=new_save_path

        tf.reset_default_graph()

        with tf.variable_scope("model1"):
            self.hidden_1_layer = {
                    'weights' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.num_input,
                                self.n_nodes_hl1]), name='Weight1')
            }
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), self.save_path)
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    def save_model(self):
        self.saver.save(self.sess, self.save_path)

    def load_model(self):
        self.saver.restore(self.sess, self.save_path)

    def run_model(self):
        print("model1 running...")
        load_model()
        x = sess.run(self.hidden_1_layer)
        print(x)

    #train_model(self)
```

This way you could simply do:

```
import model

m1 = model('model1/model1.ckpt') # These two lines could be put into one
m1.run_model()                   #  m1 = model('model1/model1.ckpt').run_model()

m2 = model('model2/model2.ckpt')
m2.run_model()
```

You still want it in a **for** loop?

```
import model

model_file_list = ['model1/model1.ckpt', 'model2/model2.ckpt']

for model_file in model_list:
    m = model(model_file ).run_model()
    # Run tests, print stuff, save stuff here!
```

Comment: Well, I tried to do that in different combinations and unfortunately it still doesn't work. If it were, I would not post it on stack :)

Comment: Ok, but this is obvious that importing after running model works. I want to have imports in one place in code.

Comment: Then I suggest you to go for separate graphs! Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955144/working-with-multiple-graphs-in-tensorflow

Comment: I suggest an alternative: You can encapsulate the whole model in a class and use it like that, running `tf.reset_default_graph()` upon creation of the object. I'll show you in this answer. This way you're also avoiding code repetition.

Comment: And there it is! using classes is much more elegant and you only have your imports at the beginning!

Comment: Sorry, I did it now, but also tried to do it before I posted it on stack and I still get exactly the same error... Bu for me is important to have many different models at the same time.

Comment: May I ask why? are you sending intermediate results from one model to another? If you just need to run both models inside a script, I don't see why would you need several graphs

Comment: I have a few different models solving the same problem but in a different way. I wanted to compare them so I created a simple tool to compare and I wanted to run each model in a loop one by one.